# Insert all rows from one table into another that dont have a similar value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One master and one smaller. I just want to insert all of the rows from the smaller into the master that do not have the same value in a certain field. What I have tried is not working.  Also is there a way I can specify all values in row and not list them out individually?

Something like...

```
Update Master
Set Master.[All Values] = Smaller.[All Values]
Inner join Smaller on Master.No = Smaller.No
where Master.No <> Smaller.No
```

Comment: Have you tried a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: No I am newer to sql queries but understand the different joins. Could you show this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be that you are trying to equate and negate on the same column (.No)  - which will never return any rows. I believe you meant to negate on a different column.

Also, you will need to specify each field for the update statement. 
Here is an example of what I think you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE [master] (a int, b int, c int)
CREATE TABLE [smaller] (a int, b int, c int)

INSERT INTO [master] (a, b, c) 
  VALUES (1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (4, 2, 4), (5, 3, 5), (6, 5, 6)
INSERT INTO [smaller] (a, b, c) 
  VALUES (3, 1, 3), (4, 0, 4), (5, 0, 5), (7, 8, 7), (8, 13, 8)

-- note values for 'b' on row 4, 5
SELECT * FROM [master] 

UPDATE [master] 
SET [master].b = [smaller].b, 
    [master].c = [smaller].c
FROM [smaller] INNER JOIN [master] 
  ON  [master].a = [smaller].a 
  AND [smaller].b <> [master].b

-- note values for 'b' on row 4, 5
SELECT * FROM [master] 

DROP TABLE [master] 
DROP TABLE [smaller]
```